# Reading from threaded object only when there is no lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

Ok, i know this is normally not a thing you would want, but i can't seem to figure a good way around it.

I have Main thread, and a worker thread.
When the worker thread is done, it locks and object that main thread wants to read every frame. (once every 16ms)
Now the data is locked and takes a while for the worker thread to update this data. (66ms in this case) Which means that the main thread will run into the lock and stick there for 50~ms just waiting for the lock to go.

Now i want this main thread to update whenever the worker delivers new data. But i do not want the main thread to lock up when this worker thread locks that data. I want the main thread to just skip that part and work with outdated data for that frame.

Seeing how long it takes the worker thread to fill that data up, it seems like it would take roughly as long to update a backup/outdated data copy for the main thread. And since the code isn't mine in the first place, i can't just go about throwing the worker thread around to implement an A/B registry for that whole object (so it switches new and old every time for the cost of using 2x the memory)

Is there any way to go about this without locking my main thread, and not missing any data updates either? (for example, worker could almost immediately RELOCK the thread if the main thread doesn't grab it the nanosecond it releases)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Monitor.TryEnter()` will return false if you cannot acquire a lock on your object. Just have your main thread caller return/sleep/delay for a bit if that fails. I would strongly suggest reviewing your locking policy on your update thread if at all possible. It sounds as if the lock is being held for entirely too long. The lock should only be held for the time it takes to update the shared object, not the entire time it takes to process/prepare new data.

Comment: Thanks, i was trying to find out how to work that TryEnter thing, i though it would lock my thread even when no lock was gotten, and then just wouldn't get my anywhere. Sadly the code is not mind, and i can not really do a lot about how or when it locks. The code seems a pain to go through, but i agree something must be taking awfully long there. But it is a generic lock, not specific to access of 1 variable or array so yeah...

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Can you create an answer, because using TryEnter is exactly what i wanted to use in this case. I agree that re-evaluating the locking code in general would be the ultimate solution to this issue, but for now this will do. application no longer stutters, gets updates nearly every frame. It is magical.